# Swift Update ViewController Variable with results of dataTaskWithRequest

Tags: ios, swift

I have seen similar posts on this, but nothing that is helping me out.  I can not for the life of me determine why I can't extract data from my task. I am trying to update an object (myUser) with data obtained from a SOAP XML response from a Web Service I built.  I am new to Swift and IOS, but I've done this with C#.  I can update the label on the viewcontroller with the results from the web service, but not a class variable.  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel! //CAN UPDATE THIS FROM TASK
    var myUser = User() //CAN NOT UPDATE THIS FROM TASK
    func soapRequest(){
    ...
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error)-> Void in
           do{ xmlResponse = try AEXMLDocument(xmlData: data!)}
           catch{print("\(error)")}

           //Example of the data I am trying to send to the ViewController object
           let firstName = xmlResponse.root["element1"].stringValue

           //I've tried this
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
              self.myUser.firstName = firstName //This does not work
              self.label.text = firstName //This DOES work
           })
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: please paste code and what you have tried to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi DeyaEldeen, I posted my question prematurely and then added the code later.  Do you see it now?

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work"? What happens?

Comment: I mean it runs just fine but the value does not set.  I ran a print(myUser.firstName) and nothing shows up in the console.  To add to this, if I set a breakpoint after the update inside of the dispatch, the object does have the value set correctly.  However, the value does not appear in the console after trying to print from the viewcontroller.

Comment: Where are you printing `myUser.firstName`?

Comment: From the viewDidLoad function.

Comment: Your network request is asynchronous, it won't have finished yet when you print the value in `viewDidLoad` so the value won't have been set yet.

Comment: Ah, ok...  So how do consume the data once the request is done?

Comment: Put your code that needs the data in the completion block like you did for the `self.myUser.firstName = firstName` line.

Comment: Ok, so basically I am doing that already...  My print just didn't work because the request hadn't completed yet.  I think I am starting to understand what you're saying.  I'll play around get back to you.  Is there a way for me to mark your comment as correct?

Comment: That was it!  Since this is a tabbed view controller app, I switched the other tab and moved back to the first one and placed the same print statement in the viewDidAppear() function and it's printing!  Thank you so much!  I don't even want to admit how long I've been struggling with this.  If you post your answer I'll be happy to mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan's comment was the correct solution to my issue.  The code was executing correctly, but since the request is asynchronous, it wasn't finishing in time and I assumed it was broken.

> Your network request is asynchronous, it won't have finished yet when
>   you print the value in viewDidLoad so the value won't have been set
>   yet. – dan 1 hour ago